# Calling A Function In External Javascript Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having trouble calling an external javascript function from my asp.net page

I have a file called user.js which I have this..

```
 UseThisNewThing:function () {
 alert("In Function External");
 }
```

My asp.net page references this file in the head tag..

```
<script src="Js/User.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now I wanna call this function via jquery so in the code behind I have this

```
 if (page != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scriptName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scriptCommands))
            {
                Type parentType = page.GetType();

                // Check to see if the include script exists already.
                if (!page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(parentType, scriptName))
                {
                    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(parentType, scriptName,
                        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\njQuery(document).ready(function () {" + scriptCommands + "});</script>"); ;
                }
            }
```

where parentType is this.Page, `scriptName="InitPage",` and

```
scriptCommands=@"User.UseThisNewThing();"
```

I must be miossing something in this hook up beacuse I cannot get the alert to fire on page load

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Where do you define `User` here?  Is `UseThisNewThing` a method on the class `User`, or is it just a method defined in `user.js`.  If it's a method on a class, you'll need an instance of the class to use it.  If it's just a method in the file, you should remove the `User.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the user is name of class than you scriptcommand will be

```
scriptCommands=@"new User().UseThisNewThing();"
```

you cannot call the function direcly without creating instance of class